# Abstract Algebra: Let G be a set of symmetries of an object (Proof Verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

From the book: Abstract Algebra, an Inquiry Based Approach by Hodge, Schlicker,& Sundstrom.

Definitions from the book:

1. a **rigid motion** in the plane is a bijective function $f:\Bbb{R^2}
       \rightarrow \Bbb{R^2}$ such that for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ the
   distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is the same as $x$ and $y$.
2. A **symmetry** of a geometric object is a rigid motion $f$ s.t. $f(O)=O$. Also, symmetry refers to either rotation or reflection

Prove that the composition function is associative.

**Proof**:
Let $f_1, f_2, f_3 \in G$ be symmetries of an object $O$. Since $\forall i\in \Bbb{Z}, f_i\in G$ is such that $f_i(O)=O$, then

\begin{align}
f_1\circ (f_2\circ f_3)(O)&=f_1(O) \\
 & = O \\ 
 & = (f_1 \circ f_2)(O) \\
 & = (f_1\circ f_2)\circ f_3(O) \\ 
 \end{align}
Q.E.D.

Is the proof correct, the book does not come with a solutions manual so I want to know.

Comment: "Prove that the composition function is associative." But what composition function? Composition of functions is always associative. I suppose you want to prove that $Sym(O)$ is a group, right?

Comment: Actually, I'm also confused as to what the book meant. The approach of the book is to basically ask the reader questions that leads to the primary results of groups. However, this early in the chapter, it started with symmetries of polygons then I got this question at the end of the chapter. So I assume that composition means "succession of actions"